# Show the inclusion $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb R)^{I}\supseteq Q$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, probability-theory, measure-theory, borel-sets

Let $I$ be an uncountable set and consider the product sigma algebra on $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb R)^{I}$

I want to show that $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb R)^{I}=\{ \{f \in \mathbb R^{I}\lvert (f(t_{1}),f(t_{2}),...)\in A\}\lvert (t_{n})_{n\in \mathbb N}\subseteq I,\; A \in \mathcal{B}(\mathbb R)^{(t_{n})_{n \in \mathbb N}}\}=: Q$

I have already shown the inclusion $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb R)^{I}\subseteq Q$ by using the fact that $Q$ is a sigma-algebra and the preimages of projections of measurable sets indeed lie in $Q$

Apparently the direction $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb R)^{I}\supseteq Q$ is the easier one but I am lost on how to go about it.

Attempt: Assuming that I have  $M:=\{f \in \mathbb R^{I}\lvert (f(t_{1}),f(t_{2}),...)\in A\}$ such that $(t_{n})_{n\in \mathbb N}\subseteq I,\; A \in \mathcal{B}(\mathbb R)^{(t_{n})_{n \in \mathbb N}}$. Then if $A$ is of the form $A=\prod\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}A_{t_{i}}$ for $A_{t_{i}}\in \mathcal{B}(\mathbb R)$ clearly:

$M:=\mathbb R^{I\setminus (t_{n})_{n \in \mathbb N}}\times A= \bigcap\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}p_{t_{j}}^{-1}(A_{t_{j}})\in \mathcal{B}(\mathbb R)^{I}$. But my issue is that not every $A \in \mathcal{B}(\mathbb R)^{(t_{n})_{n \in \mathbb N}}$ is of the form $A=\prod\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}A_{t_{i}}$. But I know that the set

$$\mathcal{C}:=\{ \prod\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}A_{t_{i}}\lvert A_{t_{i}}\in \mathcal{B}(\mathbb R)\; \forall i \in \mathbb N\} $$ is a generator of $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb R)^{(t_{n})_{n \in \mathbb N}}$. Is there any way I could use this generator to extend the result, like one usually does with the monotone class theorem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If my understanding of your notation is correct then $M$ is a Borel subset of $\Bbb R^I$, being a preimage of a Borel set $A$ by the (continuous) projection map from $\Bbb R^I$ to $\Bbb R^{\{t_n\}}$.

Comment: Oh, I thought that the Product $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb R)^{I})$ is only generated by the the "single" projections $p_{j}:  (\mathbb R)^{I},\mathcal{B}(\mathbb R)^{I})\to (\mathbb R, \mathcal{B}(\mathbb R)$ such that $p_{j}$ is continuous for any $j \in I$. How does this imply the continuity of the projection $\mathbb R^{I}\to \mathbb R^{(t_{n})_{n \in \mathbb N}}$?

Comment: @MinaThuma The projection $p:\Bbb R^I\to \Bbb R^{\{t_n\}}$ is continuous because for any canonical base open set $U$ of  $\Bbb R^{\{t_n\}}$, $p^{-1}(U)$ is a canonical base open set of $\Bbb R^I$.

Comment: Yeah, but I do not understand why this continuity holds?

Comment: @MinaThuma You do not understand why for any canonical base open set $U$ of  $\Bbb R^{\{t_n\}}$, $p^{-1}(U)$ is a canonical base open set of $\Bbb R^I$ or why this condition implies the continuity of $p$?

Comment: Why any canonical base open set $U$ of $\mathbb R^{t_{n}}$, we have $p^{-1}(U)$ is a canonical base open set of $\mathbb R^{I}$

Comment: @MinaThuma To simplify the notation, put $T=\{t_n\}\subset I$. Given a canonical base open set $U$ of $\Bbb R^T$, there exists a finite subset $F$ of $T$ and a family $\{U_f:f\in F\}$ of open subsets of $\Bbb R$ such that $U=\{(x_t)\in\Bbb R^T: x_f\in U_f\mbox{ for each }f\in F\}$. Then $p^{-1}(U)=\{(x_\alpha)\in\Bbb R^I: x_f\in U_f\mbox{ for each }f\in F\}$ is a canonical base open set.